# Docker pull Unauthorized: Authentication required

Tags: windows, docker

I'm new to Docker and have installed docker desktop and signed in. I was given instructions from a colleague to pull an image, as follows:

```
docker pull petebunting/au-eoed-dev
```

I tried this on both my windows and Mac machines recently and had no issues. Now the image has been updated, but when I try pulling the latest version of the image I keep getting the error:

```
unauthorized: authentication required
```

It begins to pull down the updates but then suddenly stops and produces the above error. This update works fine on my Mac but not on my windows machine. I have tried logging in with both docker desktop and by using docker login but this makes no difference.

I am using windows 10 and powershell

I have searched through similar questions but either my question appears to be different or I do not understand the specifics of the question/answer

So my question is, is there a way to overcome the authentication error I am receiving?

Comment: I met the same error when I tried to log into an invalid docker registery. After logged in the default registry with `docker login` command, I can pull docker images again.

Comment: I got the same error. I uninstall and reinstall Docker and the problem has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

This may be caused by your incorrect host clock: https://github.com/DeepVAC/MLab/issues/60